# Passing a string containing double quotes from a node.js script to a VBScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vbscript

I have a node.js script that calls a VBScript, passing a string as a parameter.

master.js:

```
'use strict';

var str = 'This string contains "double quotes".';
console.log("In JS: " + str);

const
    spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawnSync,
    vbs = spawn( 'cscript.exe', [ 'slave.vbs', str ] );

console.log("In VBScript: " + `${vbs.stdout.toString()}` );
```

slave.vbs:

```
Option Explicit

If 0 < WScript.Arguments.Count Then 
Dim str : str = WScript.Arguments(0)
End If

Wscript.Stderr.WriteLine str
```

Console output:

> In JS: This string contains "double quotes".
>
> In VBScript: This string contains \double

This is no good, I need them to be the same. After some research I found out that the escape character for VBScript is the double quote itself. So if I want a string literal containing double quotes in VBScript, it must be declared like this:

```
Dim str : str = "This string contains ""double quotes""."
```

With that in mind I changed my master.js code:

```
'use strict';

var str = 'This string contains ""double quotes"".';
console.log("In JS: " + str);

const
    spawn = require( 'child_process' ).spawnSync,
    vbs = spawn( 'cscript.exe', [ 'slave.vbs', str ] );

console.log("In VBScript: " + `${vbs.stderr.toString()}` );
```

New console output:

> In JS: This string contains ""double quotes"".
>
> In VBScript: This string contains \\double quotes\\.

Still no good. How can I accomplish this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can write an explicit chr() call :

```
var str ='This string contains' & chr(34) & 'double quotes' & chr(34) &'.';
```

Comment: This does not work and causes an error because chr() is not defined in Javascript. Also the & character is not used for string concatenation in Javascript.

Comment: I have given the syntax for a valid vbscript output. You can replace parts of Javascript string to obtain the valid vbscript output.

Comment: Right, but I am trying to create the string in Javascript and pass it to the VBScript. Using the Javascript equivalent to your answer, var str ='This string contains ' + String.fromCharCode(34) + 'double quotes' + String.fromCharCode(34) + '.';  This does not work and still gives the wrong output. I am beginning to think what I'm trying to do just cannot be done and I will need to try a different design.

Comment: I meant that you could have a strJS and a strVBS, each one with the appropriate syntax, where strVBS is obtained by replacing parts of strJS ( " with chr(34), etc.)